# WordPress pagination - Adding an Anchor link

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pagination, anchor

I have this anchor link in my index.php:

```
<a name="blog"></a>
```

I would like this anchor link to work When next_posts_link and previous_posts_link are clicked on so it doesn't go all the way to the top of the page. I have no idea how to go about doing this for WordPress pagination though.

Here is my code for the pagination:

```
<div class="pagenavi">
<?php if( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi ' ) ) {
wp_pagenavi();
} else {
next_posts_link ('<div class="arrow-back"></div>'); }
previous_posts_link('<div class="arrow-forward"></div>') ; }
```

Comment: There seems to part of your question that's missing..

Comment: Did you paste this correctly? Where are the quotes around the HTML code or the closing )'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 2:

Adding anchor tag #blog to the prev/next links in a blogpost using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pagenavi a').each(function(i,a){$(a).attr('href',$(a).attr('href')+'#blog')});
});
</script>
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mfeldheim/EkMfP/12/

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the wp_pagenavi function seems to encapsulate the complete link building.

If you can't configure a generic postfix in your wordpress or plugin configuration I don't recommend to change Wordpress code.

Instead you could execute a small JavaScript which moves the browser page to the anchor on load.

This example uses jQuery. Paste it into a bottom location of your template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('html, body').scrollTop( 
            $('[name="blog"]').offset().top 
        );
    });
</script>
```

Couldn't test this but should work. Even simple scripts are the hell to write on a iPhone keyboard..

EDIT:
Works like a charm, check this out for a demo
http://jsfiddle.net/mfeldheim/EkMfP/7/

Comment: This does work but for some reason it doesn't go to where I've placed the anchor. It goes to the div above instead. I've checked and I've definitely put the anchor in the right place...

Comment: Also I want it to always be at the top on page load unless the user clicks the next/previous post links on the blog, but this solution would always have it go to anchor on load.

Comment: In this case my solution will not work because JavaScript can't determine how you opened the post. Instead you could add the #blog to the next/prev links using JavaScript