# Anchor link on WordPress Pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, anchor

I'm having an issue with placing an Anchor link on WordPress Pagination. I tried the suggestions found here on stackoverflow. But nothing worked so far. Now I'm trying this way. Also not working. Any suggestions? thanks a lot

```
<a name="anchor"></a>
    <?php
                        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 3;
                        $query4 = new WP_Query( array( 
                            'before' => 'href="#anchor"',
                            'after' => '</a>',
                            'post_type' => 'post', 
                            'posts_per_page' => 6, 
                            'paged' => $paged,
                        ));
                            while($query4->have_posts()) : ?>
                            <?php   $query4->the_post();?>  
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li> 
                                    <?php
                 endwhile; ?>
                 <?php 
                 next_posts_link( __( 'Ältere Artikel' ), $query4->max_num_pages ); ?>
              <?php         
                    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to start by giving us a proper explanation of what you actually want to _achieve_ here.

Comment: What you are passing as `before` and `after` here makes absolutely no sense as arguments for WP_Query. These parameters limit post selection by _dates_.

Comment: You probably want to pass some parameters influencing how the links are created to `paginate_links` or something instead …?

Comment: this worked finally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362026/wordpress-pagination-adding-an-anchor-link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mfeldheim/EkMfP/12/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress pagination - Adding an Anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362026/wordpress-pagination-adding-an-anchor-link)